# The request resource is not available

Tags: java, servlets

I am running Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7. I am making a basic Hello World program using servlets. When I run the program on my local host I get:

> HTTP Status 404 - /website2/WEB-INF/classes/T.java
>
> type Status report
>
> message /website2/WEB-INF/classes/T.java
>
> description The requested resource (/website2/WEB-INF/classes/T.java)
>   is not available.

where "website2" is my project and `T.java` is my page name.

Comment: You should not directly point to the Java class but to the URL where it is configured, e.g. `/website2/T`...

Comment: @user2461247 - take off the .java on the end of your URL

Answer (score 2):

When you create `servlets` you do not directly access the classes.
There are two ways of defining the servlet mappings either through `annotations`, or through `web.xml`.

### Through Annotation

Servlets using the 3.0 specification have a annotation that specifies the servlet-mapping... you should check this to see which URLs are mapped to your class/servlet.

Have a look at: http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/07/31/annotation-processing-in-servlet-specification-3-0/

You should have a line starting with `@WebServlet`, for example:

`@WebServlet(name="HelloWorldServlet", urlPatterns={"/foo", "/bar"})`

In the example above, the servlet `doGet` and `doPost` methods are executed when the URLs `serverName:Port/foo` and `serverName:Port/bar` are accessed either by PUT or GET.

### Through Web.xml

If your using the older specifications, you need to check the `web.xml` file that has the mapping in XML format.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>watermelon</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>myservlets.watermelon</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```